# Fill string with four digits

Tags: c#, string, formatting, string-formatting

I need to format a string to four characters, i get data from 0 to 4 characters, all the characters that are not filled must be filled with `'F'` to the left, example:

```
string Data = "1T1";
//do somthing
Data = "F1T1";

or

string Data = "X";
//do somthing
Data = "FFFX";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by `PadLeft`

```
Data.PadLeft(4,'F');
```

Comment: Thank you verry much! i thought that pad was move to left. i'll accept your awnser as soon as i can.

Answer (score 3):

Sound like you need [`PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx) method:

```
Data = Data.PadLeft(4, 'F');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a method like;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(AddF("11"));
    Console.WriteLine(AddF("1T1"));
    Console.WriteLine(AddF("X"));
}

static string AddF(string s)
{
    if (s.Length < 4)
        s = s.PadLeft(4, 'F');
    return s
}
```

Output will be;

```
FF11
F1T1
FFFX
```

HERE a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/jJ4rV7).

[`String.PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx)

> Returns a new string that right-aligns the characters in this instance
>   by padding them on the left with a specified Unicode character, **for a
>   specified total length**.

Answer (score 2):

[String.PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx)

```
string str = "forty-two";
char pad = '.';

Console.WriteLine(str.PadLeft(15, pad));    // Displays "......forty-two".
Console.WriteLine(str.PadLeft(2, pad));     // Displays "forty-two".
```

Comment: :-) There is much pretty same answers.